# Nodejs scaling and prioritising functions

Tags: node.js, performance, architecture, scalability

We have a node application running on the server that gets hit a lot and has to compile a zip file for download. That works well so far but I am nervous we will hit a point where performance becomes an issue.
*(The application is currently running with [forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever) on a ubuntu 14.04 machine.)*

I am now asked to add all kinds of new features to the app which are more secondary and should not decrease the performance of the main function (the zip download). It would be OK to have those additional features fail in case the app is hit too many times in favour of the main zipping process.

What is the best practise here. Creating a REST API for the secondary features and put everything into a waiting list? It surely isn't enough to just create a second app and spawn a new process each time the main zip process finishes? How Can I ensure the most redundancy? I'm not talking about a multi-core [cluster](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) setup or [load-balancing on NGINX](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html), but a smart way of prioritising application functions on application level.

I hope this is not too broad. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, everything should be using async I/O, no synchronous I/O anywhere in your server.  That's the #1 rule for building a scalable node.js server.

Second off, the highest priority tasks that have any significant CPU usage should be allowed to use multiple cores.  If, as you say, the highest priority tasks is creating the zip download, then you should makes sure that that operation can take advantage of multiple cores.

You can accomplish that either with clustering (your whole server runs multiple instances that can each be on a separate core) or by creating a set of processes specifically for creating the zip files and then create a work queue in the main process that feeds these other processes work and gets the result back from them.  This second option is likely a bit more complex to code than clustering, but it does prioritize the zip file creation so only one core is serving other server needs and all other cores of working on zip file creation.  Clustering shares all cores with all server responsibilities.

At the pure server application level, your server can maintain a work queue of all incoming work to be done no matter what kind and it can prioritize that work.  For example, if an API call comes in and there are already N zip file requests in the queue, you could immediately fail the API call to keep it from building up on the server.  I don't think I'd personally recommend that solution unless your API calls are really heavy operations because it's very hard for a developer to reliably use your API if it regularly just fails on them.  They would generally find it better for the API to just be slow sometimes than to regularly fail.

You might not even have to use a queue, you could just use a counter to keep track of how many ZIP file requests were "in process", but you'd have to make absolutely sure the counter was accurate in all cases.  If there was ever an accumulating error in the counter, then you might just end up failing all API requests until your server was restarted.

Comment: I like your count proposal. I guess that's what I was alluding to. Cheers